# why is message printing out the quotation marks in python? python super beginners code

Tags: python

my code is:

```
import base64

def encrypt(cleartext, key):
   new_message = cleartext,key,23
   return new_message


message = encrypt("heckin", 9)
print (message)
```

and I receive:

```
('heckin', 9, 23)
```

How do I get rid of the ' ' and the parenthesis marks on the output? so it could just be: 
    `heckin 9 23`
(completely new to python. i know its an overly easy solution for you guys)

Comment: `print(message[0])` will give you the first index of the tuple. If you were to write to a file or something, the `'` wouldn't exist, it's to tell you that the value is a string

Answer (score 4):

You're returning three things from your `encrypt` function. Those three things go into a tuple, which has its own rules for how it is printed, and it shows as `('heckin', 9, 23)`.

You can print each element of that separately:

```
message = encrypt("heckin", 9)
print(message[0])
print(message[1])
print(message[2])
```

Or all three in one line:

```
print(*message)
```

which is equivalent to

```
print(message[0], message[1], message[2])
```

Output:

```
heckin 9 23
```

---

Alternatively, it might be more clear if you unpack the return value into three variables.

```
message, key, number = encrypt("heckin", 9)
```

To print all three in a line, it would be:

```
print(message, key, number)
```

Output:

```
heckin 9 23
```